# Can I update kSecAttrApplicationTag using SecItemUpdate?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, keychain

Here is my code:

```
var query: [String: Any] = [
                kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
                kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: currentTag
            ]
            var attributesToUpdate: [String: Any] = [
                kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
                kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: archiveTag
            ]
osStatus = SecItemUpdate(query as CFDictionary, attributesToUpdate as CFDictionary)
```

The error that I got back was One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I removed kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey in attributesToUpdate and it worked